# Recursive function without loops or variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am learning coding by myself. I am taking learning recursive function from online resources, and as an exercise, I came across this one exercise where I am tasked to create a recursive function to see if numbers in the list are in order. The exercise says not to use loops and not to use variables, so I can learn recursive function better for the future.

```
 def is_increasing(lst):
  if not (lst[0]) < lst[1]:
    return False
  else:
    return is_increasing(lst[1:])
```

when I input **is_increasing([1,2,12,24])** in the console.

The **errors says:**

**IndexError:list index out of range**

**What am I doing wrong that is showing this error?**

Comment: Because at last iteration there won't be an element with index `1`..

Comment: An important part of recursion is testing the base case. Eventually there will be one thing left in the list.

Comment: This is a poor way to implement it, since slicing a list creates a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't take the recursion far enough. You are assuming that a list will have at least two elements, but that's not true for empty and singleton lists. (Plus, at no point did you ever attempt to return `True`.)

The true base case is a list with fewer than 2 items, which is trivially sorted. Otherwise, you can check whether the first 2 elements are in order, then recursively check the rest of the list.

```
def is_increasing(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return True
    else:
        return lst[0] < lst[1] and is_increasing(lst[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a stop condition (or base case) for every recursive function, otherwise it won't stop: in your case, the stop condition is if the list contains one elements or less, it's always sorted:

```py
 def is_increasing(lst):
  if len(lst) <= 1: return True # Base case

  if not (lst[0]) < lst[1]:
    return False
  else:
    return is_increasing(lst[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

When implementing a recursive function, there is always one special case which has to be handled differently: how does the recursion stop?

The implementation show here correctly reduces the problem of solving an input of size N to a problem of size N-1:

```
def is_increasing(lst):
  if not (lst[0]) < lst[1]:
    return False
  else:
    return is_increasing(lst[1:])
```

What is missing is handling the situation where the size is 0 or 1. Therefore:

```
def is_increasing(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return True  # That is always sorted

    # BTW this is correct only if it is supposed to be descending,
    # oherwise it should be lst[0] > lst[1] 
    if not lst[0] < lst[1]:
        return False
    else:
        return is_increasing(lst[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function never returns `True`. That's not directly the cause of the error, but that's related to it.

For a recursive function that returns a `bool`, you need *two* base cases, not just one: one that returns `True` and one that returns `False`.

So when should it return `True`? What is the relevant base case? It is when the list is too small to fail: a list that is of length 1 or 0 is always increasing, technically. And in that case, there is no `lst[1]`, which causes the `IndexError`. So this is the solution:

```
def is_increasing(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return True
    elif lst[0] >= lst[1]:
        return False
    else:
        return is_increasing(lst[1:])
```

(You also had a mistake where you compare `not lst[0]` with `lst[1]`, I fixed that for you ;)